# Styling ordered lists with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list in HTML.
I would like to add styling only to the numbers (1,2,3,...), and not to the list items themselves.

Is there a way to refer to these numbers ?

Thanks !

Comment: stackoverflow.com faq: 'If your question is about web design and HTML/CSS layout, ask on http://doctype.com'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS2 provides for control over [generated content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html), which will let you style the auto-generated content independently of the rest of the item using the `:before` pseudoclass.  Here's a solution that meet's the OP's follow-up criteria (background color on the list enumerator but not the item).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <style type="text/css">

    body { margin: 0; padding: 10px; }
    ol {
        counter-reset: item; 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
    li:before { 
        content: counter(item);
            /* 
                To generate punctuation after the number, just precede or follow with a string: 
                content: "Chapter " counter(item) " >> ";  

                To make nested counters (1, 1.1, 1.1.1, etc.), use:
                content: counters(item, ".");
            */
        counter-increment: item; 

        background-color: #ddd;
        margin-right: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    ol li ol { margin-bottom: -10px; padding-top: 10px; }
    ol li ol li { margin: 10px 0 0 30px; }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<ol>
    <li>Turtles</li>
    <li>Lizards
        <ol>
            <li>Salamanders</li>
            <li>Geckos</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Velociraptors</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you simply style the `ol` element and then override the style on the `li` element.

```
ol
{
    color: blue;
    font-style: italic;
}
ol li p
{
    color: black;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

with

```
<ol>
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
</ol>
```

You can change the `p` tags to `<divs>` if you want, but if you keep them as `p`'s you'll have to strip margins and paddings.

Comment: -1: Doesn't work, at least on Chrome and Firefox. E.g.: http://jsbin.com/oyeya/edit

Comment: Try it now, I forgot the `p` tags.

Comment: Thanks !
How about changing the background color of the numbers ?
I would like the numbers to be with a red background and the text to be without any background. Is that possible ?

Comment: @misha: I'm not sure if that's possible, though it's defenitely a good point. [This as about as close as I could get](http://jsbin.com/oyeya/2). Though you could also strip paddings and margins and then adjust with some other divs around the `<li>` tags maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was just going to comment on cowbellemoo's answer, as it does not work in IE7 and I wanted to explain how to achieve IE7 compatability, but I suppose my solution is a totally different answer.

His answer is all good and well, but it won't work in IE7. So if that's important to you, here's another approach you can take, based off of this A List Apart article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/#custom

**The Markup**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>01.</span> Text content</li>
    <li><Span>02.</span> More text content</li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

There are a few variations on this you could do, either floating the `<span>` and giving it a width & margin, or setting the `<li>` to `position:relative;`, giving it appropriate padding, and absolutely positioning your span in its right place.